# como eliminar el botón una vez clickeado

Tags: javascript, dom

estoy empezando con javascript y lo que quiero hacer es que al hacer click en el botón con el icono de la lupa aparezca lo que agregue con innerHTML (el formulario y el input) y que el botón del icon sea eliminado, pero cuando lo clickeo, aunque ya haya aparecido el input y el form, continua al lado

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="search-remove">
  <button class="search-add" id="search-btn"><i class="fa-regular fa-magnifying-glass search-icon"></i></button>
</div>
<div id="search"></div>
```

```javascript
//Javascript
const deleteBtn = () =>
  document.getElementsById("search-remove").remove("search-btn");

document.getElementById("search-btn").onclick = function () {
  deleteBtn();
};

const searchBtn = document.getElementById("search-btn");

document.getElementById("search-btn").onclick = function () {
  deleteBtn();
};

function addForm() {
  var formStyle = (document.getElementById("search").innerHTML = `
    <form id="form" class="d-flex search-form" role="search">
    <input class="search-input" type="search" placeholder="Search coffe" >
    <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="fa-regular fa-magnifying-glass search-icon"></i></button>
    </form>
`);
}

const style = () =>
  (document.getElementById("search").style.backgroundColor = "tomato");

searchBtn.addEventListener("click", addForm);
searchBtn.addEventListener("click", style);
```

Comment: agrega tu html y css, agrega detalles para que tu pregunta se mejor recibida. Lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para tener consejos de como preguntar

Comment: En tu funcion **deleteBtn** obtienes el id del div con **getElementById** y despues lo quitas del DOM con remove, revisando tu codigo, estas poniendo una letra **"s"** de más.

Comment: ya corregí el error de la 's' pero el butano sigue aun después de hacer click sobre el